# Problems with SQL delete statement

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting an error stating that I need a second argument in my remove command, but I believe I already have two in here. I'm pretty new to SQL and C# so maybe I'm not understanding it correctly.

```
private void RemoveFromRecipeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "DELETE FROM RecipeIngredient WHERE Id = @RecipeId & @IngredientId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        command.Parameters.Remove("@RecipeId", ListRecipes.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.Remove("@IngredientId", ListAllIngredients.SelectedValue);

        command.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    PopulateRecipes();
}
```

I'm thinking it might be because I put both RecipeID and IngredientID in the same line with an &, but that works on my add statement.

So I'm really unsure of how remove should work. Can anyone assist in identifying the issue?

Comment: Why are you doing `&`? Why are you trying to remove elements from and empty collection (`command.Parameters`)?

Comment: `WHERE Id = @RecipeId & @IngredientId` is not valid SQL. What are you trying to say here?

Comment: It is valid SQL, @Blorg. Just very unlikely to be doing what the user wants.

Comment: @TZHX ah, yeah, bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Parameters.Remove` when it looks like you want to be calling `Parameters.AddWithValue`. You're executing a `delete` statement, but that doesn't mean you want to *remove* parameters. You still need to *add* the parameters that specifies what to delete.

Your actual SQL statement is suspect as well - you're currently deleting rows where the bitwise AND of your two parameters matches the `Id` of the row. Is that what you want?

Comment: The correct SQL is likely close to `DELETE FROM RecipeIngredient WHERE RecipeId = @RecipeId AND IngredientId = @IngredientId`

Comment: Eric brings up a good point about how the DELETE syntax could be changed to meet what the user most likley desired. BITWISE is probably obscure to some people reading but here is an article about it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different problems here.

The first one is I'm not sure what your sql is trying to do. Are you actually trying to perform a bitwise AND, or are you just trying to see if `Id` is equal to both the `@RecipeId` and `@IngredientID`?

Additionally, just because your SQL statement has parameters in it, doesn't mean you can use `cmd.Parameters.Remove()` to remove them. The `Command.Parameters` collection is used to associate values in your program to specific parameters in  your sql statement. You will have to remove the parameters from the literal sql string, if you are truly looking to remove them from the statement.

Comment: There's nothing invalid about the SQL. It's almost certainly wrong for what the user wants to do, but it will run.